# pip install vs python3 -m pip install

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am working in a conda environment, trying to install a package into it. On my previous computer, `pip install <package name>` within that environment worked. But on this new Mac, if I do that, and then try to import the package in that environment, it doesn't work.

This:

`pip install SpeechRecognition`

differs from

`python3 -m pip install SpeechRecognition`

The latter works below, but the former doesn't:

```
>>>import speech_recognition
>>>
```

Also, the files appear to be pointing to the same place:

```
(test) ~$ which python
/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python
(test) ~$ which python3
/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python3
(test) ~$ which pip
/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/pip
```

everything is running from the test environment.

So what's going on? and how do I fix it? I want to be able to test packages in an isolated environment reliably.

**UPDATE**

just to show that pip and pip3 are both using 3.7, not 2.7 on my machine:

```
(base) ~$ conda activate test
(test) ~$ which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3
(test) ~$ which pip
/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/pip
(test) ~$ pip --version
pip 19.1.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Or, is that the issue? that pip uses a different 3.7 from the test environment? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On many systems, `pip` uses the Python 2 interpreter, while `pip3` uses the Python 3 interpreter. When only Python 3 is installed, `pip` is identical to `pip3`. One way to know which interpreter is used, is to read the first line of the file `pip`.

`python3 -m pip install` is equivalent to `pip3` but at least it's explicit that you want to use `python3`.

In your case, it looks like `pip` uses the Python 2 interpreter but with the module that has been installed for Python 3. That's curious.

I'd recommend you to use `python3 -m pip install` instead of relying on the command `pip`.

Comment: `which` seems to suggest they’re all the same, though…

Comment: I updated notes about my environment, and it appears that pip and pip3 are in different environments. However, I was using `pip` not `pip3` in my example...

Comment: The first line of `/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/pip` is `#!/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python` @maxime

Comment: So I have some config headache. Maybe I should remove python 2.7x from this mac, but it is the OS default one, so I hesitate. I'll try to use pip3 explicitly and see if that fixes it.