# pip vs python -m pip why pip command throws a module object is not callable error

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I've seen similar posts like

[pip install vs python3 -m pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940665/pip-install-vs-python3-m-pip-install)

that does not really clarify this problem.
I am new to Python, just following a basic python 3 tutorial where they mention pip as the dependency manager, and they mention that it should be used as `pip install dependency_here`

I am using Python 3.8.0, brand new install on Windows (for all users, so that it's installed under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32`)

and I cannot run pip command. I get a module error which I have no idea what's about.

```
$ pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I can, however, use `python -m pip` command

```
$ python -m pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from C:\Users\iberodev\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

and install modules with it.

The question is why I can't use a command that most of the tutorials mention, and even the official pip repository uses for the examples:
https://pypi.org/project/Flask/#Installing

**I'd like to know why am I having that error.** since it seems not so common

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1** (2 Nov 2019): Thanks to the answer I found out the PATH for user and system was a bit of a mess.
I decided to clear it and reinstall Python 3.8.0 64bits version and it seems all good now:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.8.0
```

And pip

```
$ pip --version
pip 19.2.3 from c:\users\iberodev\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

and PATH

```
$ echo $PATH | tr \: \\n | grep "Python"
/c/Users/iberodev/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts
/c/Users/iberodev/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if you many have more than one version of python installed? `python -m pip` seems to be looking in the dir `C:\Users\iberodev\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ ` where as just calling `pip` is looking in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\"`.

Comment: yes, there was something like that. Not sure why. After reinstalling only one version I had the same problem. I suspect by then the PATH was a bit messed up and installing Python for all users was probably part of the problem. Ta. (added fix on UPDATE 1)

Comment: Probably worth you while checking out [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `path` environment variable. There's a `path` for the current user (no elevated rights, user environment variables) and a `path` for the system (elevated rights, system environment variables). Now, to call `pip` without using it as a python method (`python -m pip`),

- your `path` must include an entry pointing to the `Scripts` folder from your Python installation (and of course the entry pointing to the folder that contains the `python.exe`). This is true for whatever installation you want to use (user or system).
- if you want to call `pip` from a system Python installation to add packages to *that installation*, you'll need to call it from a command prompt with elevated rights (similar to using `sudo` on Linux).

I suspect the second point is what's causing the error you got.

Not entirely sure who creates `\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages`, but that's not where you'd find a *Python installation*. A *Python user installation* would be located in `\AppData\Local\Programs\Python`. Likely the `AppData\Roaming\...` folder is used by `pip` (out of a system installation) when called without elevated rights to install packages.

In principle, I'd suggest to have only a user installation of Python on Windows 10. For most applications, you won't need a system installation in my experience. And I'd rather use the 64bit version. But that depends on what you intend to do.

Comment: I had such a mess with the PATH that I decided to clear all and reinstall the Python 3.8.0 64 bits.

Comment: Glad it helped! Although I can't tell you *exactly* where the error you got came from ;-) anyway, since you're already at it, have a look at [virtual environments](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) as well. That's imho a good way to manage dependencies e.g. if you work on different projects.